# Counter example of linear continuum.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I was thinking about a counter example of a set that isn't a linear continuum because it doesn't satisfy the least upper bound property with the dictionary topology, but I can't found anyone.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$? $ $

Comment: Well yes, but I'm searching for an counter example in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted recently, $[0,1] \times [0,1)$ is not a linear continuum as $\{0\} \times [0,1)$ has an upper bound but no lub.